# What should be done with the tags: [a-certain-magical-index] and [railgun]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

Currently we have the tags:

- [a-certain-magical-index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-certain-magical-index)
- [railgun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railgun)

Which refer to:

- "A Certain Magical Index" or "Toaru Majutsu no Index"
- "A Certain Scientific Railgun" or "Toaru Kagaku no Railgun"

which are sister series in the same universe.

However, [a-certain-scientific-railgun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-certain-scientific-railgun) is too long to be a tag. So we currently use [railgun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railgun) instead.

But given that these two series go together, there will likely be many questions with both tags.
An example of which is: [How is Misaka's railgun so destructive?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2235/how-is-misakas-railgun-so-destructive)

But it seems inconsistent to use the full name for one, and the shortened name for the other.

---

So what should we do?

**Option 1:** Shorten them to [index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/index) and [railgun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railgun). And synonymize [a-certain-magical-index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-certain-magical-index) -> [index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/index)

**Option 2:** Switch them both to the Japanese names: [toaru-majutsu-no-index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toaru-majutsu-no-index) and [toaru-kagaku-no-railgun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toaru-kagaku-no-railgun). (Both of which fit.) And then synonymize [a-certain-magical-index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-certain-magical-index) -> [toaru-majutsu-no-index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toaru-majutsu-no-index).

**Option 3:** Leave them inconsistent as is with: [a-certain-magical-index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-certain-magical-index) and [railgun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railgun)

---

If you have other ideas, please post them.

Comment: Since I can't vote on my own posts below, I cast my vote for option 2: Switch them both to the Japanese names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vote this up for **Option 2**.

Switch them both to the Japanese names: [toaru-majutsu-no-index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toaru-majutsu-no-index) and [toaru-kagaku-no-railgun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toaru-kagaku-no-railgun). (Both of which fit.) And then synonymize [a-certain-magical-index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-certain-magical-index) -> [toaru-majutsu-no-index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toaru-majutsu-no-index).

Comment: I suggest also synonyms [index] -> [toaru-majitsu-no-index] and [railgun] -> [toaru-kagaku-no-railgun] so that they are easier to type.

Comment: Wouldn't the suggestion for "toaru-majitsu-no-index]" come up if you type "index" anyways? I think the tag [tag:index] is too vague.

Comment: @JonLin Yes it will popup. Since it matches any word in the tag. Searching for `toaru` will give both if we went with this option.

Comment: One opposition I have to this is that not everyone knows the Japanese name. Like, do many people know what *Hagane no Renkinjutsushi* is? Not likely. Additionally, what would we do if the Japanese name was too long? How can this apply to future issues of the same type?

Comment: @Eric Well, this is a special case since the keywords are "index" and "railgun" which are common in both the English and Japanese names. Furthermore we have not been consistent with choosing English vs. Japanese names. Pretty much whoever is creating the tag is picking whichever version they are most familiar with or whatever they believe is the most commonly recognized one. I'm actually against taking a hard-line approach with "English only" names since there are a lot of shows that are better known by their Japanese names - especially among those who watch primarily new shows.

Comment: You do have a point, though I still think sticking with the *best known* name is the better approach. If this does get passed, though, I would suggest that all Japanese tags have in their description the English name as well, so that someone typing "railgun" will see "toaru-kagaku-no-railgun: A Certain Scientific Railgun" (or similar).

Comment: @Eric My vision for this is that all shows have the best known name (English or Japanese Romanji). The other one is synonymized with it. The tag descriptions will have both (and the Japanese name in Japanese). For this particular case, I actually consider the Japanese romanji names to be better recognized than the English ones. But I'd expect that to change if and when the shows get dubbed in English.

Comment: That actually sounds about right. It will be a problem, though, for any series which has the "best known name" with a length longer than allowed. (Which I'm sure has already happened, even if we have no questions on it yet.)

Comment: @Eric We'll handle those on a case-by-case basis like this one. Most of the time, there will be a suitable abbreviation that fits. But in this case, that abbreviation is "index" which sounds a bit too general despite it immediately clicking to anyone who is familiar with the series.

Answer (score 2):

Vote this up for **Option 3**.

Leave them inconsistent as is with: [a-certain-magical-index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-certain-magical-index) and [railgun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railgun)

Answer (score 0):

Vote this up for **Option 1**.

Shorten them to [index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/index) and [railgun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railgun). And synonymize [a-certain-magical-index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-certain-magical-index) -> [index](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/index)